# Convert XML to JSON with XSLT 2.0

Tags: json, xml, xslt-2.0

I have a XSLT that can convert XML to JSON and it works well. But When I'm trying to modify the value type of JSON I'm unable to do so.

Below is my XSLT file code:

```
<xsl:template match="json:name" mode="json">
    <xsl:text/>"<xsl:value-of select="json:encode-string(.)"/>":<xsl:text/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="json:value" mode="json">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="node() and not(text())">
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="json"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="text()">
            <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test="normalize-space(.) ne . or not((string(.) castable as xs:integer and not(starts-with(string(.),'+') or starts-with(string(.),'-')) and not(starts-with(string(.),'0') and not(. = '0'))) or (string(.) castable as xs:decimal and not(starts-with(string(.),'+')) and not(starts-with(.,'-.')) and not(starts-with(.,'.')) and not(starts-with(.,'-0') and not(starts-with(.,'-0.'))) and not(ends-with(.,'.')) and not(starts-with(.,'0') and not(starts-with(.,'0.'))))) and not(. = 'false') and not(. = 'true') and not(. = 'null')">
                                        <xsl:text/>"<xsl:value-of select="json:encode-string(.)"/>"<xsl:text/>
                                    </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:text/><xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text/>
                </xsl:otherwise>

            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text>null</xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

I want to add a condition that if xml element name is id and it's non-null, then convert it to string.

I tried below thing, but it didn't work.

```
    <xsl:template match="id">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="id">
            <xsl:text/>"<xsl:value-of select="json:encode-string(.)"/>"<xsl:text/>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

How do I iterate over these elements as key-value pair, so I can add conditional logic to value if name matches?

Edit:

Added sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <ns0:TestMe xmlns:ns0="urn:hero:wakanda:Cle:Something">
   <root>
     <id>123</id>
     <field2>345</field2>
     <fee>
        <totalFee>123</totalFee>
    </fee>
    </root>
    </ns0:TestMe>
```

Using this XML to JSON converter file: https://github.com/bramstein/xsltjson/blob/master/conf/xml-to-json.xsl

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky I have added the required things

Comment: Can you edit the question to show us both the JSON the code you linked to creates for your shown XML sample and then explain and show how your wanted JSON output differs? It is not clear what you desired result is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of the stylesheet linked to from your question edit I think you want something like

```
  <xsl:template match="json:member[json:name = 'id']/json:value" mode="json">
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="json:encode-string(.)"/>
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
```

to get e.g. `"id":"123"` instead of e.g. `"id":123`.